# Overlay/merge images with a slanted edge

Tags: graphics

Is there away to overlay two images, I only want to see half of one and half of the other. The picture below shows the effect I'm going for. Should I just be processing my images in Photoshop or can LaTeX achieve this. I like the slanted effect but if it is easier to do a vertical split that would be good to.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `clip`. Here the clip areas are of triangular shapes, but that can be changed by different clipping area via the `clip` command, knowing that the 4 corners are (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,1) and (1,-1) with the origin at the center where the `width=height=2cm` in this example.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip[] (-1,-1) -- (-1,1) --(1,1) --cycle;
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-A}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\clip[] (-1,-1) -- (1,-1) --(1,1) --cycle;
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-B}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```